# Java sync promise (using CompletionStage)

Tags: java, playframework, promise

I am creating a promise that is not necessary.

(using Java Play WS)

```
public CompletionStage<Result> doSomething() {
    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();

    /*
     * Promise not required. Just return BadRequest.
     */
    if (json == null) {
        // I think I am overkilling it here
        ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
        result.put("error", "some error");
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {return 0;})
                .thenApply(i -> badRequest(result));
    }

    /*
     * Promise required.
     */
    return ws.url("http://www.example.com/")
            .get()
            .thenApply(response -> {
                String body = response.getBody();
                // Do something
                return ok(body);
            });
}
```

I need the return to be `CompletionStage<Result>` because of the second part of my code.

Do I really need all this async code for that simple response? My `return 0` is useless for the code, except for not raising a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

It was easier than expected. The `return 0` it totally unnecessary because it can be replaced by the actual return code, also avoiding the `thenApply` repetition.

So, the part that does not require promise can be replaced by:

```
    if (json == null) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
            result.put("error", "some error");
            return badRequest(result);
        });
    }
```

And also, [Java Play `Result` and `CompletionStage<Result>` are handled by the same way](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaAsync#Actions-are-asynchronous-by-default).